# VM can't ping LAN name but sees it via nslookup

Tags: networking, virtualization, dns, vmware-fusion

I am trying to connect to a network resource from my 10.04.4 VM (VMware Fusion) but the destination is unreachable by name.

What is weird is that the name is visible in DNS:

```
>nslookup my.name
Server:     123.45.67.89
Address:    123.45.67.89#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   my.name
Address: 10.20.30.40
```

I can reach it (via ping) by the IP address (10.20.30.40) but not the name and I thought that was weird because the DNS clearly resolves the name.  What can I do to enable access to this resource via the name?

Comment: Is this a server installation? To close voters: 10.04.4 is on topic till 2015.

Comment: yes, server installation

Comment: Edit your question with a traceroute to each address.

Comment: What do you get when you ping the name? Does ping resolve the name correctly?

Answer (score 0):

I would try the basics first.

Do you have a name caching daemon installed.
If so:

```
/etc/init.d/nscd restart
```

Next check if you have some iptables rule causing this.

```
iptables -F
```

That would flush your rules, and from there try again.